# how can I disable or enable the auto rotation?

Tags: eclipse, java-me

Can anyone tell me how to disable or enable the auto rotation?
I do not want to start an activity in landscape or portrait mode.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

It is device dependent.
Some devices lets you set auto-rotation on/off via JAD/MANIFEST attributes. But others gives you no control whatsoever.

Same question was asked 2 years ago here:
[How to lock the landscape mode in j2me app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098607/how-to-lock-the-landscape-mode-in-j2me-app)

Comment: I dont want to lock my app in landscape or portrait mode, i want to change cellphone setting.

Comment: Not possible with JavaME, sorry.